# Adding a node to a cluster when elasticsearch was installed via homebrew on mac OS?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, homebrew

I've been looking online to find a way to add nodes to a cluster when elasticsearch was installed via homebrew but to no avail.

I thought I found a solution by following this post: [Getting an ElasticSearch Cluster to Green (Cluster Setup on OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944915/getting-an-elasticsearch-cluster-to-green-cluster-setup-on-os-x)

But after launching (or so I thought), my elasticsearch-full name (the original elasticsearch installed via homebrew) is now giving an error when using `brew services list`, and everytime I try to restart it, the error stays. Now, I deleted the new plist to try and get elasticsearch-full (original elasticsearch and original plist) back to starting, but it is stuck on error.

So, I still don't know how to add a node to a cluster and now I have this error and I've been stuck all day. Does anyone have a solution to both problems :/ ?

Comment: What's the error then?

Comment: You want to run 2 instances (nodes) of Elasticsearch server on a single Mac computer, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think the command that you are looking for to start up a new node on an index is the following:

```
bin/elasticsearch -Enode.name=node-2 -Epath.data=./node-2/data -Epath.logs=./node-2/logs
```

In terms of the error I don't think I can be much help as I am just learning ES myself.